# Не могу добавить представление в mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Не получается добавить представление в mvc 5. Появляется следующая ошибка

> There was an error running the selected code generator 
>   "An item with the same index has already been added"

В проекте использую последние стабильные версии *Ninject*, *Ninject.MVC3* и *Moq*.

Код контроллера и метода действия, к которому хочу добавить представление:

```
public class ProductController : Controller
{
    private IProductRepository repository;
    public ProductController (IProductRepository productRepository)
    {
        this.repository = productRepository;
    }

    // empty view  "List" with model class "Product"
    public ViewResult List()
    {
        return View(repository.Products);
    }
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить проблему.

**Обновление**

В папке `Views/Product` пусто. Нет ни файла `List.cshtml`, ни `_ViewStart.cshtml` и `Shared/_Layout.cshtml`, которые должны быть добавлены автоматически.

**Обновление 2**

```
 routes.MapRoute(
      name: "Default",
      url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
      defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

**Обновление 3**

Удалял папку `Views\Product` и создавал контроллер, не помогло. При вызове `View()`:

> Server Error in '/' Application. The view 'List' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations.

Как и должно быть когда не создано представление.

**Обновление 4**

У меня в одном решении *Visual Studio* несколько проектов, в которые я добавлял *Ninject*, *Ninject.MVC3* и *Moq*. После того как я пытался удалить их у меня возникала такая же ошибка в консоли *NuGet*.

> "An item with the same key has already been added."

После удаления и переустановки *Visual Studio* и выполнения всего необходимого для решения вопроса https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24429838/installing-nuget-package-same-key-has-already-been-added ошибка с добавлением представления исчезла.

Comment: А может оно правда уже создано?

Comment: Нет, его нет. Обновил вопрос.

Comment: А роутинг настроен на `{controller}/{action}`?

Comment: @Qwertiy Обновил вопрос

Comment: Удалите папку Views\Product и пересоздайте контроллер.

Comment: Если использовать вызов View(), будет ли работать?

Comment: @pavelip Обновил вопрос.

Comment: @pavelipОбновил вопрос